# What is the difference between a block of data and a page?

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, operating-system

I often come across the phrase 'block of data'. One such example is as follows.

'The basic file system exchanges fixed-sized pieces (blocks) of data with the device drivers, buffers those blocks in main memory, and maps blocks to their physical location.'

Is this the same as a page? If not, what are the differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A BLOCK is the basic unit of physical storage on a disk.
A PAGE is the basis unit of memory allocation.

The PAGE size and the BLOCK size may or may not be the same size.

One might say that a memory PAGE is analogous to a disk BLOCK.